# Restrict output of decimal number to specific precision

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

Please help me regarding output **999999.35**? in angular or java script with  html means that i want to restrict 9's up to 6 digits before decimal point after 6 digits it don't accept any digit and after decimal point restrict up to 2 digits only.  please help me regarding this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is many kind of inbuilt filters are available in angular , let me show you one of them,

**filter allows us to limit the number of decimal places a number can show. To pass the argument 2,**

we’ll append :2 to the number filter:

```
<!-- Displays: 123.46 -->
{{ 123.456789 | number:2 }}
```

**This is not the exact answer you want**, but you can play around it and even you can make your own custom filter which will return exact output you want.

Let me know if you want idea that , how to make our own custom filter.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your answer could you explain in brief

Comment: Try this by writing it in you ap's any view, you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Use this `regex` matcher to validate your number

```js
function isValid(number){
    //return new RegExp(/^(\d{1,6}.\d{2})$/).test(number);//for any number
 //return new RegExp(/^([9]{1,6}.\d{2})$/).test(number);//for only 9
  return new RegExp(/^([9]{1,6}.\d{2})$/).test(number);//for less then 6 digits
}
console.log(isValid(9999.35));
console.log(isValid(999999.35));
console.log(isValid(99999.35));
console.log(isValid(999999.3545));
console.log(isValid(99999999.3545));
console.log(isValid(999999.95));
console.log(isValid(899999.35));
```

Comment: it should accept below 6 digits also but not exceeding, after 6 digits text box  will not accept input

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer you are looking for,

**I have taken a regular expression to allow 6 digits before and 2 after decimal places**

And I have taken a directive to **restrict the input if the pattern fails**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
});
app.directive("validateWith", [function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, $el, $attrs){
            var regexp = eval($attrs.validateWith);
            var origVal;
            // store the current value as it was before the change was made
            $el.on("keypress", function(e){
                origVal = $el.val();
            });

            // after the change is made, validate the new value
            // if invalid, just change it back to the original
            $el.on("input", function(e){
                if(!regexp.test($el.val())){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $el.val(origVal);
                }
                
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" required validate-with="/^\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/">
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the snippet**

[Here is a plunker for it.](https://plnkr.co/edit/xvux4Iu0OJ7ua9kylTLY?p=preview)

Comment: @Varahala Babu, please check my answer.

Comment: here showing error instead of that text box will not accept input 6 digits before and 2 digits after decimal point

Comment: you can prevent the form from submitting, if you have an error in the input.

Comment: can you explain in brief

Comment: your solution is ok but there when you long press key it is accepted

Comment: check now. I think your requirement is achieved.

Comment: hello, checked my latest answer?

Comment: @Varahala Babu, please check now.

Comment: again problem is there multiple dots allowed in your code

Comment: which browser you are using, it is working fine here in chrome and firefox. have you checked the plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using *ng-pattern* is correct. Just try adding the attribute **step** to the same tag.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/" required step="0.01">
```

The step attribute specifies the legal number intervals for an  element.

Comment: with ng-pattern we are able to showing error instead of that text box will not accept input 6 digits before and 2 digits after decimal point